# Use Spreadsheet for Extruded Profiles

Tags: python, drivers, properties

I use Blender for technical constructions. Therefore I created for example a bunch of HEA profiles (https://www.ezzat.org/de/Querschnittswerte/gewalzt/I/hea.php). I saved each of them in a single *.blend-file. I combined each with a hook-modifier and an empty which is driven by a custom property. This works fine so far.

But right now I have the problem of standardized tubes having certain lengths like 1984 mm, 984 mm and 200 mm. Only these lengths should be available. I have tried using an array custom property and thought you can switch the single values. But I am only offered to input all value and not to choose one. I'd like to put something like a spreadsheet in the background of the object where I can pick the desired value from using a custom property.

Does this work without python? And if not: Can anybody help me or give me the starting kick to set up python driven properties?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems what you are looking for is enum properties, wich you can only define with python scripting

Answer (score 2):

Open the *Drivers editor* from context menu:

[image]

Select all points and set interpolation to *constant* by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

Now set up the Key frame and values 0.200/200mm, 0.984/984mm, 1.984/1984mm.
To add a new point, click on points area with holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Now then you move the value slider it snaps to only three allowed values:

[image]

This is not a perfect solution, but requires no scripting

Comment: nice! And learnt today already something useful!!! +1

Comment: @Crantisz Didn't hink about keyframing. At first glance this looks pretty smart. But the issue is if I have several profiles in one *.blend-file I am chained to the timeline.  And dependeing on the frame the lenghts of the profiles vary.</smart>.

Comment: This is not keyframes, actually, This is drivers, they are not existing on the timeline

Comment: <smart> I got it. Almostly exact what I wanted. No spreadsheet but similar. And to finalize I adjust the custom propertiers of the profile to intger and the min and max count of states I want to allow. Great thanks to @Crantisz. I think Chris was mentally faster than me :-)